# Storing differnt values in char* vector, all positions in array have same value

Tags: c++, arrays

**Let me explain my problem**

First of all, imagine I randomly generated the number "5".

> I want to convert this integer to a char* so I can display it using my
> Draw_String() method.
>
> I want to have "5" as the central position which would be [1] in a
> char* array[2].
>
> In position [0] I want the lower adjacent number "4"
>
> In position [2] I want the higher adjacent number "6"

so

[0] = 4
[1] = 5
[2] = 6

Then I want to display the contents of the vector positions, like this.

```
4
5
6
```

However, my output is more like this:

```
5
5
5
```

No matter what number I generate, and no matter which operations I perform, I will only get the number "5" in all of my vectors positions.

**Code**

```
int startpoint = rand() % 7 + 1;
int assigner = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    startpoint += assigner;
    convert = std::to_string(startpoint);
    char *converted = &convert[0u];
    blocks.push_back(converted);
    assigner++;
}

//spin around twice for visual effect.

for (int counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
{
    Draw_String(drawY, drawX - 1, blocks.at(0));
    Draw_String(drawY, drawX, blocks.at(1));
    Draw_String(drawY, drawX + 1, blocks.at(2));
}
```

if anyone could help out I'd appreciate it.

Don't ask me to get rid of `char*`.

Comment: Try using `string`. It is much harder to get `char *` right, and it's generally a waste of time.

Comment: I require the use of char*.

Comment: I bet you don't. You can convert for output when you need to.

Comment: Which is what I do.

The code is the conversion process.

Or are you suggesting I have the vector of characters and then convert?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior: it harvests a pointer to the internal string buffer from inside the `conver` string

```
char *converted = &convert[0u];
```

but the buffer can become invalid the next time `convert` string is re-assigned. The behavior that you see suggests that the buffer gets reused, rather than re-allocated, so the same pointer gets stored in the `blocks` vector.

The best solution would be to store `std::string` directly, because it would manage both copying and de-allocation for you:

```
std::vector<std::string> blocks;
...
blocks.push_back(std::to_string(startpoint));
```

If you insist on using pointers, make a copy of the string before adding it to the container:

```
char *copy = new char[strlen(converted)+1];
strcpy(copy, converted);
blocks.push_back(copy);
```

Now you are required to call `delete[]` on each element of `blocks` when you are done in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum Is there a specific part or term that you do not understand?

Comment: Then I'm pushing a string to the back of a string array, I still need to convert it to a char* for my output method, which is the full problem to begin with.

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum Why? Simply call `c_str()` on the object, and you would have your `const char*` which is guaranteed to stay until your string is changed or deleted. Make sure the code accepts `const char*`, though, to ensure that it is not trying to modify the content of the string.

Comment: But then it's a constant, and it needs to change. and it doesn't accept const char*

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum Why would `Draw_String` need to change what's passed into it?

Comment: @JohnnyMccrum Is it your function or someone else's? If it is yours, change it to accepting `const char*`. It would still let you call it with `char*`, but `const char*` will be an option as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you needto use char* and not std::string than you need to allocate it and copy content of the string intead of copy the pointer.

instead of:

```
char *converted = &convert[0u];
```

use:

```
char *converted = malloc(convert.length() + 1); // number + '\0'
// can also use char *converted = new char[convert.length() + 1];
strcpy(converted, convert.c_str())
```

Now, no matter what happens to convert, you have control on your *converted* data. (take care to also delete it when you don't need it)

Otherwise when convert changes, converted can change or point to invalid data. 
This is because in the original implementation converted is pointing to data that is managed by convert object.

Comment: what are you using for the second parameter of strcpy?

Comment: Why would you use `malloc` in C++ over `new[]`?

Comment: I have no ideea, please use a debugger and findout where the problem is.